# Why does my phone not find appex when I flash gsi?

Tags: custom-roms, boot-loop

Every Time I flash a gsi be it a only or A/B gsi. it doesn't boot. Twrp recovery reports that Evey time I flash a gsi system my device doesn't have have Apex in system_root/Apex when I flash the stock super.img it then boots

Comment: What device are you talking about?

Comment: the device is tecno kd7